# org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: The object name is not found [0xC0000034]

Tags: javascript, kotlin, compiler-errors, opc, kepserverex

I am having a problem using "J-INTEROP" trying to make an OPC DA client for andriod devices.

I made all the DCOM configurations and today I can connect to the server from any PC that is within my network regardless of the user that connects.

The error that is throwing me is: org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: The object name is not found [0xC0000034]

The OPC DA server I am using is KepServerEX.V4

The error occurs in the following line: val comServer = JIComServer(JIProgId.valueOf("KEPware.KEPServerEx.V4"), "192.168.1.11", session)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.jacob.com.Dispatch
import org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException
import org.jinterop.dcom.common.JISystem
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.IJIComObject
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIProgId
import org.jinterop.dcom.core.JISession
import org.jinterop.dcom.impls.JIObjectFactory
import org.jinterop.dcom.impls.automation.IJIDispatch
import java.net.UnknownHostException



class MainActivityOPCDA : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var errortextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_opcda)

        errortextView = findViewById(R.id.etextView)

        Thread(Runnable {
            JISystem.setInBuiltLogHandler(false)
            JISystem.setAutoRegisteration(true)


            
            val session = JISession.createSession("192.168.1.11", "opcuser", "123456")
            session.useSessionSecurity(true)
            session.globalSocketTimeout = 5000



try {

   val comServer = JIComServer(JIProgId.valueOf("KEPware.KEPServerEx.V4"), "192.168.1.11", session)


   val serverObj = comServer.createInstance() as IJIComObject

   val opcServer = JIObjectFactory.narrowObject(serverObj.queryInterface("6E6170F0-FF2D-11D2-8087-00105AA8F840"))

                val opcServerDispatch = opcServer.queryInterface(IJIDispatch::class.java.name) as Dispatch
                val server = Dispatch.call(opcServerDispatch, "QueryInterface", IJIDispatch::class.java.name).toDispatch()




            } catch (e: JIException) {

                e.printStackTrace()
                runOnUiThread {
                    errortextView.text = "ERROR: ${e.message.toString()}"
                }


            } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                runOnUiThread {
                    errortextView.text = "ERROR: ${e.message.toString()}"
                }
            }
 }).start()


    }
```

I did a lot of testing on the DCOM setup. Assuming a problem with some windows permission, for these tests I am using Windows 10. And the tests are with real andriod devices.

I also did tests with different OPC DA clients for windows and the communication with the server works correctly for me.